# Cannot run two different CompilationTask from one JavaCompiler

Tags: java, compilation, annotations, protocol-buffers

Why we can't run two different compilation tasks twice?
I use Java compiler API but when i try to get another task from java compiler and then call it - thrown IllegalStateException.
As described in this Javadoc:

```
         * Performs this compilation task.  The compilation may only
         * be performed once.  Subsequent calls to this method throw
         * {@code IllegalStateException}.
         *
         * @return true if and only all the files compiled without errors;
         * false otherwise
         *
         * @throws RuntimeException if an unrecoverable error occurred
         * in a user-supplied component.  The
         * {@linkplain Throwable#getCause() cause} will be the error
         * in user code.
         * @throws IllegalStateException if called more than once
         */
        @Override
        Boolean call();
```

But, i cannot understand why?

My idea is build a library that generates .proto files from Java classes, compile this proto files with protoc compiler - so it create some new Java files (with Protobuf generated classes), and then creating a Converter classes that converts from generated to source class and back.

I wrote an annotation processor for my annotations, and it worked. Also, i wrote a code that used external Protoc compiler to generated new Java classes. But after that i try to create another dynamic compilation task with newly generated Java classes and another annotation processor to generate Converter's, but unfortunately.

How can i call compilation twice? Or do you have better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at there is the `JavaCompiler.CompilationTask` interface  It is designed to be called once.

We can't tell you why the interface was designed that way because we weren't involved in the design process.  My *guess* is that the designers considered the following:

- typically you don't perform *the same compilation* multiple times
- you would like the compilation to be done asynchronously
- a non-reusable task simplifies compiler implementation.

But it doesn't really matter.  It *was* designed this way, so you need to work with it.

> How can I call compilation twice?  Or do you have better ideas?

1. You can't.
2. Create a new `JavaCompiler.CompilationTask` for each compilation that you want to perform.   The javadoc for `JavaCompiler.getTask` states that it creates a new `CompilationTask` instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's copy-paste error(